# Ruby/Rails rspec download errors on run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, rvm

I get the following error while running

```
saasbook@saasbook:~/Documents/ruby-calisthenics$ rspec
```

error message

```
/home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:167:in `find_formatter': Formatter 'nested' unknown - maybe you meant 'documentation' or 'progress'?. (ArgumentError)
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/formatters.rb:126:in `add'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:624:in `add_formatter'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:106:in `block in load_formatters_into'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:106:in `each'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:106:in `load_formatters_into'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/configuration_options.rb:24:in `configure'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:96:in `setup'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:85:in `run'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:70:in `run'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:38:in `invoke'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/gems/rspec-core-3.0.3/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
from /home/saasbook/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p481/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

I am a newbie to Ruby and Rails. I have been having compatibility issues across the board, any help would be appreciated!

a bit of background of the file directory im trying to run rspec in | it's a file from an online class i am taking. it contains a lib and spec file as required. but the error im getting seems to be an issue with my rspec download.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit the `.rspec` file in the root of your Rails application directory and change the following line from:

```
--format nested
```

to:

```
--format documentation
```

The `nested` format no longer exists in rspec-3.0.

Comment: You don't have to upvote, but you need to mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstall all previous versions of rspec and its dependencies.

```
gem uninstall rspec
gem uninstall rspec-core
gem uninstall rspec-mocks
gem uninstall rspec-expectations
```

Install the correct version of rspec in gem file [install rspec](https://github.com/rspec/rspec-rails).

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails', '~> 3.0.0'
end
```

I got this solution from this [link](http://edx-cs169-1x.stackexchange.com/questions/2638/cs-cs169-2x-oracle-of-bacon-homework-autotest-error/2642#2642)